# Convert NodeJS HTTP post script to Python

Tags: python, node.js, http-post, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to call this Node.JS script (which is a unit test) to Python equivalent. It basically generates an AWS token, and uses that to send a .json file as HTTP post request. How can I re-write it in Python? I already did the token generation part.

Here is the NodeJS script:

```
describe('Send config file', () => {
  let token = '';
  before(function beforetest(done) {
    this.timeout(10000);
    tokengen(cognitoUser, authenticationDetails).then((result) => {
      token = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      done();
    }, (err) => {
      done(err);
    });
  });

  it('should send config json', function test(done) {
    this.timeout(10000);
    chai.request(app)
      .post(`${route}/sendjson`).set('accesstoken', token)
      .send(vcamconfig)
      .end((err, res) => {
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
        expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
        expect(res.body).to.have.property('msg');
        expect(res.body.msg).to.equal('Uploaded to S3');
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

And here is the python script I attempted so far to generate an AWS token. I need to use the token to send a file as a POST request.

```
from warrant.aws_srp import AWSSRP
import boto3

username = "user3"
password = "user3"
client_id = "myclientID1234567890"
user_pool_id = "us-east-1_sdhjsasls"
region = "us-east-1"

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=region)

aws = AWSSRP(username=username, password=password, pool_id=user_pool_id, client_id=client_id, client=client)
tokens = aws.authenticate_user()
print(tokens)
```

Comment: Why not use the existing node code?

Comment: I'm not a node guy and if I want to add more features later, it will be difficult for me.